# Ubuntu grepping strings with missing spaces

Tags: grep, gnu

let's say I had the email test1234test@test.com in a file which contains a list of emails. But, instead of having the entire email, I only had (for example)
t**********t@test.com

How would I grep this that way i could grep for all emails that could have missing spaces to fit in that string? In order for this to be working, I should be able to grep for the string equivalent to t**********t@test.com and have it find test1234test@test.com ... ? Also, it would find other emails that could fit in those asterk spaces such as test4321test@test.com ? Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you mean by ********** : are you trying to match any name that starts and ends with letter `t`? or only names that are a specific number of characters long? What do you mean by "missing spaces". Examples might help. Does the file have exactly one email address per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep takes '.' as 'any character'. So

```
grep "t..........t@test.com"
```

will do that. (Nice to solve crossword puzzle :-)

Comment: `grep "t.\{10\}t@gmail.com"`, pretty please?

Comment: This works.. however, what if i wanted it to only be a letter or number?

Comment: Then the syntax used by kos is nice. It is repeating a pattern 10 times without typing it 10 times. So you can do `grep "t[0-9a-z]\{10\}t@test.com"` for getting only digits and small chars. There are plenty of short cuts for sets of characters. Have a look [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html). To fit any number of digits and letters replace `\{10\}` by `*`.

Comment: To dive into the ocean of regular expression possibilities, you should have a look at a [tutorial](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/unix/grep.html) and later in a [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/). If you use regular expressions not only to filter (using `grep`) but also to manipulate (e.g. using `sed`) you will find the power of them.